# Elastic Beanstalk upgrade single-instance without replacing EIP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a single-instance `t2.medium` `Node` `Beanstalk` app that I want to upgrade to `t2.xlarge`.

However, last time I updated from small->medium, the `IP` for the server got replaced and this led to IT having to make a few changes with `DNS`, emails, etc..

Is there any way to keep the same `IP` while updating just the instance?

Thanks!

Comment: If you already have an Elastic IP associated with your instance, you can always disassociate it, upgrade the instance and associate it back to the new instance that will be created. Writing a script for this will help you automate the procedure.

Comment: This solutions seems to mostly work for us. However, the new instance can have a different local IP when its rebuilt, is there anyway to keep that one the same too? Thanks

Comment: I allocated the new EIP and associated it with the created ec2 to test if it will remain if I deleted the existing ec2 and the environment tried to create it. Shockingly right after assigning the new EIP, the ec2 reverts back to the original one that was created with it.
any help?